# Save data under same uid Firebase swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added some data to the Firebase Realtime Database. It's in two parts, users and bookings. My problem is that when a user books a ride it gives a different uid, I would like it to be when a user books a ride it is under the same uid. Also, if the switch is on I would like to put it under the same child node, booking, but it comes into different nodes when saving. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
   func Save(){

    let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
    
    let Booking = [
    
        
        "id": key as Any,
        "What Date": atALaterDate.text! as String,
        "What Time": hoursMinutesTextField.text! as String,
        "To What Time": ToWhatTime.text! as String,
        "Requests or Notes": SRtextfield.text! as String

    ]
    
    as [String : Any]
        
    ref.child(key!).setValue(Booking)


    }
```

this is where I would like it to be under one node, in conjunction with the one above it.

```
func Save2(){

    let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
    
        if Switch.isOn{
            
            let passengers = [
            "Passengers": Stepperlabel.text! as String,
            "passenger Age 1": AgeOfChild1.text! as String,
            "passenger Age 2": AgeOfChild2.text! as String,
            "passenger Age 3": AgeOfChild3.text! as String,
            "passenger Age 4": AgeOfChild4.text! as String,
            "passenger Age 5": AgeOfChild5.text! as String,
            "passenger Age 6": AgeOfChild6.text! as String,
      
                ]
            
            as [String : Any]
                
            ref.child(key!).setValue("booking")
                
                
                
        }else{
            print("Hello")
                return
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not sure I understand the question based on the code. This line `let key = ref.childByAutoId().key` generates a new node key in both Save and Save2, so the data would be stored within different child nodes each time it's called. If that's NOT what you what, then why include that line? What is `ref` referring to? Also, please ensure var's are lowercased, this `.setValue(Booking)` referrs to a Structure or Class. Lastly this `.setValue("booking")` just writes the string "booking" to a child node so not sure of what that's for. Can you clarify the quesiton (and code)?

Comment: Hi, when I remove `let key = ref.childByAutoId().key`, my function doesnt save in the database. To clarify my question; I would like to put both save and save 2 under the same node, but I do not know how, as I have limited knowledge in swift and firebase.

Comment: Furthermore, var ref: DatabaseReference!, is what ref is reffering to.

Comment: My question about that line of code was because each time you run either Save or Save2, a new node will be created. If you want to store additional data with the same node, you need to use the same reference. I will illustrate with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question is how to add additional data to a node.

The important bit is to keep a reference to the node you want to write to and use it with `update` to add/change existing data. If `update` is used on a node that doesn't exist, it will be added.

So here's an example. Suppose we have a chatting app and we want to write an initial String of *Hello, World*, and then add an additional string of *What's up?* to that same node

```
let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages") //the top level node
let thisMsgRef = ref.childByAutoId() //create a child node
        
thisMsgRef.setValue( ["msg": "Hello, World"]) //create the node, write data
thisMsgRef.updateChildValues(["anotherMsg": "Whats up?"]) //add addl data
```

this results in the following structure

```
messages
   -Jy444f476u6...
      anotherMsg: "Whats up?"
      msg: "Hello, World"
```

If you want to re-use the node over and over, a reference to it could be stored as class var and then anytime you want to write to it, just reference the var...

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {  
    var myMsgRef: DatabaseReference!
```

then somewhere later in code

```
func writeInitialData() {
   let ref = self.ref.child("messages")
   self.myMsgRef = ref.childByAutoId()
   self.myMsgRef.setValue( ["msg": "Hello World"])
```

and then when you want to add additional data

```
func addAdditonalData() {
   self.myMsgRef.updateChildValues(["anotherMsg": "Whats up?"])
```

Comment: How would I save the uid to write another node under the same user uid?

Comment: @Hello-World I addressed that in the answer a bit - *If you want to re-use the node over and over, a reference to it could be stored as class var* - there are many ways to do it though. A class var is just one option. Keep in mind that if you're using Firebase Authentication, the users UID is always available from the [Auth.auth().currentUser.uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) var as well.